# Why did my machine stop booting?

Tags: boot, grub, linux-mint, bootrepair

All of a sudden when I turned on my Linux Mint 14 machine I got the following message:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'
```

...and a grub rescue prompt. I ran the Boot-Repair tool (via a live CD), and it gave me [this output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6095197/). I then tried rebooting, and I still got the same error. Is there any reason for this sudden behavior?

Comment: Did the boot-repair tool fix your problem or does it still persist?

Comment: still persists. I guess that wasn't clear.

Comment: Did you make any changes in the machine, like adding/removing/changing harware? Any disk management stuff being done before shutting it down the last time when it still worked?

Comment: none of the above. And nothing else significant....

Comment: I see you've also tried to get help in (Linux Mint forums)[http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=144889&sid=df12b10937ea3c334067d6887362cda6]. I was wondering the same as proposed there, that your root partition starts from curiously far from the disk start. Also the Grub files are located very far from the disk start so I wonder if it simply is a problem of Grub not being able to reach for them (I admit I do not know the current state of boot-time restrictions on disk layout, but I always have a small /boot partition at disk beginning to avoid having to battle this).

Comment: So you haven't done any restructuring of partitions, no defragging, no installing of updates that touch the system base (grub, kernel) after the last successful reboot? I find it extremely odd if booting starts failing on a disk that looks otherwise healthy per the repair tool output if nothing has been touched... Can you get the system to boot from the disk using the live CD?

Comment: What if you try the following at grub rescue prompt: `cat (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` ?

Comment: I will have to try these things when I get to my machine at home tonight. @zagrimsan, I haven't done any of the above unless some system update happened without my knowledge. per your question: Can I get the system to boot from the disk using the live CD? I'm not sure I quite follow. I can boot the machine from the live CD but i'm not sure what you mean by "boot from disk using the live CD"?

Comment: I meant that are you able to boot with live CD so that you just use the CD basically as a boot loader, having it boot using the root file system on the disk. I have no experience on Mint but I'd assume there is a way to pass something like `root=/dev/sda1` or `root=UUID=82083ab6-130c-463e-b0d9-f08e52c4aeb0` (as your grub config does) on the live CD boot menu as a parameter for the kernel (or even have there a choice to boot the OS from the disk instead of the one on the CD).

Comment: Were you able to get it working, Ramy?

Comment: thanks for following up, guys. I haven't had a chance to try any of this stuff yet - i've just been running the machine from the livecd in the meantime for the bare minimum stuff I need to do. Will update when I can get some time to dig into this.

Comment: @zagrimsan - could you give me some step by step instructions how to do that, perhaps generally ifnot specifically for mint. I'm unsure how to proceed with your advice.

Comment: Also, I tried running the cat command you passed along at the grub rescue prompt. I got `unknown command 'cat'`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have any boxes which use Grub, and neither do I have experience on Mint per se, but maybe [this could help you out](http://tuxers.com/main/instigating-a-manual-boot-from-the-grub-prompt/) (look under the heading *Fixing the boot from the Grub prompt*)? If in doubt with what the commands really mean, take a look at the [Grub manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html). I'm sorry for leaving you to figure it out yourself but understanding the boot process certainly is worth studying since it will make you feel more comfortable when boot issues arise.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Mint installation media boot prompt, but I'd expect either "Boot from local drive" followed by `tab` key to let you edit the boot options. Otherwise, pick a live CD of your choice and there should be an option like *rescue* or similar.